# setState changes state but doesn't re-render

Tags: reactjs

2nd question from my 1st react project and not grasping why I can't seem to effect a render in a component.

I've read lots of posts that talk about how React re-renders components and sub-components when setState is called (unless utilizing shouldComponentUpdate), but in my component, I see my state change using console.log, but the actual content doesn't re-render.

Below, you'll see a skeleton of what I'm trying to do. This DisplayLightbox component takes a showLightbox=true prop from a parent component that displays it (when the css class lb-active is added to the div, hidden becomes displayed). When I click the onClick on the image, I see the new url change the state inside of the displayImage function using console.log(this.state.activeImage), so that seems good, but nothing changes in the render. I've even added the state activeImage as a div class, just to see if that displayed the new url - it does not and just shows the initial/image.

If I close the lightbox by setting lightboxValue to false and reopen it, setting it to true, it does respect the new state and shows the second image.

I'm guessing it might have something to do with opening from a parent, but I have other components that change from states changing within them, so I'm a little baffled as to why this one doesn't respect it's new state.

Thanks

```
class DisplayLightbox extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showLightbox: false, 
      lightboxValue: null,
      activeImage: 'path/to/initial/image'
    };
    // I saw others recommend binding, not sure I'm using this right
    this.displayImage = this.displayImage.bind(this);
  }

// as I understand it, this should be unnecessary, as it should be true by default
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    return true
  }


  displayImage(newImage){

    if(newImage){
      this.state = {
      activeImage: newImage, 
      };
    }
    console.log(this.state.activeImage) // when I click the onClick below, I see the new change in my console to the new image path, so the state is changing

    return this.state.activeImage
  }


  render() {

    var lbActive = (this.props.showLightbox === true) ? "lb-active" : "" 

    return <div className={"lightbox " + lbActive }>
      <div className={"lightbox-content " + this.state.activeImage} >
      <img src={this.state.activeImage} onClick={() => this.displayImage('path/to/NEW/image')}
      />
      </div>
    </div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Never, ever (!) mutate `this.state` directly. Always use `setState()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to update the state you need to call it as a fuction and not setting its properties directly.

Instead of:

```
this.state = {
  activeImage: newImage
}
```

make use of:

```
this.setState({
  activeImage: newImage
})
```

Be aware that `this.setState` is [asynchronous](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) and therefore `this.state.activeImage` will not be updated on the next line (in case you try to `console.log` afterwards)

Comment: Fantastic! That works. I'll keep to myself how long and how many things I tried to solve that problem before reaching out to the pros. Thanks for clarifying that for me.